# How to adjust start points for multiple highchart series?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I use React Highchart for rendering some metrics.

I have problem with start points when i have multiple data series. They need to start from left border - all, but data series have different values (timestamps) (expected). Is there any highchart API or idea how to adjust start points to start from left border-all.

Existing situation: [image]

Comment: If the series have different x values (timestamp) and you want them to start from the left - then for each series, you need different scale (x axis) - http://jsfiddle.net/vk3od3jc/ I am not sure if this is you are asking, though.

Comment: As Morgan alluded to, the points will be plotted wherever their x values are. You can skip sending the `x` values in the data, and specify the `pointStart` and `pointInterval` values in your `plotOptions`, or individually in each `series` object - http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.pointStart | http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.pointInterval